# How do we use every: do: method of pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I've looked in the pharo book and I couldn't see any examples of `every:aDuration do:aBlock`. I found a `Timespan` class which when ran does give an error when the object is created and the method is called.

```html
|plan|
plan := Timespan new.
plan start.
" save the file every 30s"
plan
   every:30 seconds do:[ Transcript show:'My message']
```

Comment: There are several examples in the tests. Open Pharo and browse the `TimespanDoTest` class. You also need to provide an argument for the `do:` block.

Comment: TimespanDoTest does not have a method every: do:

Comment: The class that implements `every:do` is `Timespan`. The `TimespanDoTest` class implements methods for testing `TimespanDoTest>>every:do:`. You can take a look at those tests to understand how to use the `Timespan` protocol, including `every:do:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timespan's every:do: doesn't schedule events. You might try forking a background process with a Delay to do that.

I have only Squeak handy at the moment, but it should be more or less the same.

Something like this:

```
planProcess := [
                 [ 30 seconds asDelay wait.
                   Transcript show: 'Saved (but not really)'; cr.
                 ] repeat.
               ] fork.
```

To end the process:

```
planProcess terminate.
```

There's also a Scheduler you could use for this.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @fede s

Comment: @ludo, no prob! I figured mostly by your comment to the other answer, so for your next Q try to be extra explicit just in case (what's obvious to you might not be to others). BTW, I don't rate this A more than "quick and dirty", take it as a point to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

```smalltalk
|span aDate|

aDate := DateAndTime year: 2012 month: 12 day: 12.
span := Timespan starting: aDate duration: 1 minute.
span every: 10 seconds do: [ :each | Transcript show: each; cr ].
```

Output:

```
2012-12-12T00:00:00+00:00
2012-12-12T00:00:10+00:00
2012-12-12T00:00:20+00:00
2012-12-12T00:00:30+00:00
2012-12-12T00:00:40+00:00
2012-12-12T00:00:50+00:00
```

Comment: I do the same but it does not repeat every 10 seconds. And how can show a message intead?

Comment: @ludo - `Timespan` doesn't  *repeat every 10 seconds*.  It's simply creating those `DateAndTime` objects at 10 seconds intervals for you within the time span of 2012-12-12T00:00:00 upto (but not including) 2012-12-12T00:01:00

Comment: I think @ludo might be looking for something like `[ 5 timesRepeat: [ 5 seconds asDelay wait. Transcript show: 'Hi!'; cr ] ] fork.`

Comment: Yes fede thanks, I was looking for something that could repeat with delay. So Timesapn does not repeat. My mistake @draegtun thanks.

Comment: @fedes. - Yes and this was covered in an earlier SO question with ludo - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473641/how-can-i-refresh-a-session-for-every-60-second-and-display-it-on-transcript-wit/47486747#47486747

Comment: Heh, I see. Well, with the traffic in [Smalltalk] I don't think it's a problem to have new users asking simple questions ;) I'd like some more traffic in [factor-lang] too tbh...

Comment: @fedes. - Yes it's OK for simple questions because I'm also a new user of Smalltalk and didn't even know about `Timespan` until i answered this question :)