# How can we fill a html text area on pharo

Tags: html, smalltalk, pharo, pharo-5

For a login through pharo using the html form there is a method of Znclient which is formAt:add: followed by a post. So I was wondering how to I fill a textArea of html form and make post. Is there a method for such action?

```html
<div><textarea id="technique" name="technique" class="technique">jumping</textarea></div><label>Résultats :</label>
<div><textarea id="resultat" name="resultat" class="resultat">Higher score</textarea></div><label>Conclusion :</label>
<div><textarea id="conclusion" name="conclusion" class="conclusion">Best jumper of the school</textarea></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking into `ZnClient` class in the System Browser you can see the comments for following methods:

`formAt:add:` - *"Add key equals value to the application/x-www-form-urlencoded entity of the current request. This is for multi-values form fields."*

`formAt:put:` - *"Set key equal to value in the application/x-www-form-urlencoded entity of the current request."*

`formAdd:` - *"Add the key->value association to the application/x-www-form-urlencoded entity of the current request."*

`formAddAll:` - *"Add all key->value associations of keyedCollection to 
    the application/x-www-form-urlencoded entity of the current request."*

We haven't used `formAt:add:` in any of our previous [q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47486747/12195) on this and we should avoid it here. Use one of the last 3 methods:

```smalltalk
| client |
client := ZnClient new url: 'http://server/some-script.cgi'.
```

then...

```smalltalk
client formAt: 'technique'  put: 'foo'; 
       formAt: 'resultat'   put: 'bar'; 
       formAt: 'conclusion' put: 'baz'; 
       post.
```

or...

```smalltalk
client formAdd: 'technique'  -> 'foo'; 
       formAdd: 'resultat'   -> 'bar'; 
       formAdd: 'conclusion' -> 'baz'; 
       post.
```

or this...

```smalltalk
client formAddAll: {
    'technique'  -> 'foo'. 
    'resultat'   -> 'bar'. 
    'conclusion' -> 'baz'.
} asDictionary; post.
```

Comment: This seems not to work for the textarea form. Is there a way perhaps to remplace the value contained in the textarea?

Comment: @ludo - Http POSTing just sends form name & data pairs (key/value) and so doesn't care if its a `<textarea>` or not.  So above does work (I did test it when I made the answer).  So you're experiencing a different problem which more detail or most likely a new question maybe required to resolve this.

Comment: Yes you are right It works. My problem was that I was missing another text area different from the listed above. Thanks @draegtun

Comment: @ludo - You're welcome, glad you have now resolved it.